# Facebook Graph API, Unable to get user profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I http using graph API explorer in the context of "Graph API Explorer", I am able to query user information as -
      /v2.0/{user-id}

when I http in the context of my app, I see the response as:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Permission lists are same both on Graph API Explorer as well as my App:

user_about_me
user_activities
user_birthday
user_events
user_friends
user_likes
user_location
user_photos
user_status
user_videos
email
publish_actions
read_friendlists
read_stream

Comment: What access token are you using? the implication is that you're not using one

Comment: Try with another user-id, someone can dis-allow people to get his/her profile. Or, the user-id was deleted from Facebook.

Comment: are you using a user access token for the user you are trying to the infos for? what exactly is your http call?

Comment: btw, that is a heavy list of permission. are you sure you need all of them or is it just for testing?

Comment: I am using the token generated using graph api explorer, I believe it attached automatically to all outgoing requests. I was using my own user id, and I got this error.

Comment: @luschn yeah, I mean these are for other purposes I need in my app. I added my broad list in the question, than being specific

Comment: how would a token generated in the api explorer get magically attached to your own http request? it would help to know what exactly you are doing, including the code.

Comment: @luschn idk if I made my point, using the Graph API explorer,I believe graph API explorer auto attaches token to each request. There is no coding involved all the request is made directly using Graph API explorer tool provided by fb. I observed in developer tools in chrome that access token is auto attached by fb for all rest http urls

Comment: it does, but of course ONLY in the api explorer.

Comment: but you still did not tell us what exactly you are doing (in your app or wherever) outside the api explorer.

Comment: @luschn My issue seems to be resolved by generating new access token and using different set of userids. My use case was to fetch user info and display that on app - eg: about me, birthday, etc. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regenerated a new access token and tried different sets of user ids and it seems to be working now.